# OnDraw in android ImageView, Whats wrong

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

Guys I want to draw a arc using different colors, but it doesn't show anything on activity at all, I am new to android,

Thanks,

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    try {
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        Path obj=new Path();
        RectF rf=new RectF();
        RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 500, 580);
        canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true, paint);


        int i;
        for(i=0;i<500;i++)
        {

            Thread.sleep(10000);
            paint.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
            canvas.drawPath(obj, paint);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a pencil in onDraw bad practice. (Long operation)

2) You need super.onDraw

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
```

3) Remove Thread.sleep (10000);

4) You need an [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that will call invalidate() in onProgressUpdate. Your code will look like this:

```
class StupidTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<500;i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            paint.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
            publishProgress();
        }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            postInvalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            invalidate();
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to display, like an animation , which continuously draws until we stop them. thats why I used thread, can you suggest me how can I do that?

Comment: @RussianFederation onDraw method is called in the main (UI thread). When you do what you do, UI thread hangs forever in your onDraw method, causing Android fail to redraw anything! You MUST call invalidate() method to redraw. This answer suggests doing it in asynctask. This IS the correct answer in fact.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the onDraw method actually needs to complete.  So try doing your thread sleeping in the activity and invalidate the view every 10 seconds, which will call onDraw again

Answer (score 0):

1) If you just want to draw a arc using different colors,this is my code.

```
paint = new Paint();
rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 500, 580);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
paint.setStrokeWidth(12);

int startAngle = 90,sweepAngle = 45;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    paint.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, paint);    //绘制圆弧
    startAngle += sweepAngle;
}
```

2) You can use canvas.drawPath() to draw any specified path,like that

```
rnd = new Random();
obj = new Path();
obj.moveTo(50, 100);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    obj.lineTo(rnd.nextInt(100), rnd.nextInt(100));
}
canvas.drawPath(obj, paint);
```

3) Use this view:

```
<com.zfeng.stackquesdraw.TestOnDraw
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```